# Racy tail recursive function

Tags: scala, concurrency, buffer, race-condition

I am trying to do some processing on a SynchronizedQueue using a tail recursive function.  The function seems to work properly but the more I think about concurrency the more I believe I could have some race conditions when accessing this queue with different threads.  Here is the function that I think I could use some help with:

```
val unsavedMessages = new SynchronizedQueue[CachedMessage]()

val MAX_BATCH = 256
val rowCount = new AtomicInteger()

  private def validateCacheSize() = if (unsavedMessages.length > MAX_BATCH) {
    implicit val batch = createBatch
    val counter = rowCount.getAndIncrement
    @tailrec
    def processQueue(queue: SynchronizedQueue[CachedMessage]): Unit = if (queue.nonEmpty) {
      val cm = queue.dequeue
      addToBatch(cm.request, cm.timestamp, cm.brokerId, counter)
      processQueue(queue)
    }
    processQueue(unsavedMessages)
    executeBatch
    resetQueue
  }

  def resetQueue = unsavedMessages.clear
```

Multiple threads call this function:

```
  def add(request: WebserviceRuleMatch, timestamp: Long, brokerId: String) = {
    validateCacheSize
    //log.info("enquing request "+ unsavedMessages.length)
    unsavedMessages.enqueue(CachedMessage(request, timestamp, brokerId))
  }
```

Does anyone have any pointers on how to improve this so there would likely not be a race condition?

Comment: Can you tell us why you think this code might have a race condition?

Comment: The add function gets gets called from a future so I feel as though there could be a chance that the queue gets emptied between queue.nonempty and queue.dequeue.  Also I think messages could be added by a thread between processQueue and resetQueue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there could be a chance that the queue gets emptied between queue.nonempty and queue.dequeue

- Avoid calling multiple queue operations that must be synchronized within your code.  Use the power of `SynchronizedQueue` to do atomic thread-safe operations.  E.g. avoid calling `queue.nonempty` altogether (alternative to tail-recursion):

  ```
  for (cm <- unsavedMessages.dequeueAll(_ => true)) 
    addToBatch(cm.request, cm.timestamp, cm.brokerId, counter)
  executeBatch
  //resetQueue   -- Don't do this!  Not thread-safe
  ```

> I think messages could be added by a thread between processQueue and resetQueue

- There will always be a point at which your code has taken a 'snapshot' of the queue and emptied it.  My previous point ensured that the 'snapshot' and emptying are a single atomic operation.  If new entries are enqueued at any point after that atomic 'snapshot & empty' operation - no problem.  Your 'snapshot & empty' must occur somewhere and new items enqueued are a fact of life.  Make the decision to allow new items to be enqueued at any point subsequent to the 'snapshot & empty'.  They'll be processed on next cycle.  i.e. nothing extra needed beyond above point.

> Robin Green: (By the way, that method seems to have a very misleading name!)

- Wot he said!  :)

Answer (score 1):

> The add function gets gets called from a future so I feel as though there could be a chance that the queue gets emptied between queue.nonempty and queue.dequeue.

Yes, it could. You could use double-checked locking to make `validateCacheSize` single-threaded. (By the way, that method seems to have a very misleading name!)

> Also I think messages could be added by a thread between processQueue and resetQueue.

Yes, they could. But why do you need to call `unsavedMessages.clear` at all? `queue.dequeue` already removes them from the queue. So the only `unsavedMessages` that should exist in the queue then are ones that still remain to be processed.